# Merging multiple firebase stream in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, rxdart

Guy this is a real problem merging multiple firebase streams to one stream. Someone should write an article or a simple video tutorial on this. Either using StreamGroup, FlatMap(), Rx.combineLatest, StreamZip or CombineLatestesStream. I have tried solving this since yesterday and I cant get a clear guidance.

```
class CartPage extends StatefulWidget{
   @override
   _CartPageState createState() => _CartPageState();
}
class _CartPageState extends State<CartPage> {
   
   // a firebase collection for all items
   Stream stream1 = EcommerceApp.firestore
    .collection("items")
    .where("shortInfo",
        whereIn: EcommerceApp.sharedPreferences
            .getStringList(EcommerceApp.userCartList))
    .snapshots();

   // a firebase collection for flash sales items
   Stream stream2 = EcommerceApp.firestore
    .collection("flashitem")
    .where("shortInfo",
        whereIn: EcommerceApp.sharedPreferences
            .getStringList(EcommerceApp.userCartList))
    .snapshots();

   List<QuerySnapshot> getList(QuerySnapshot list1) {
   List<QuerySnapshot> result = [];
   (list1 as List).forEach((element) {
     result.add(element);
    });
     return result;
   }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  Stream combineStream = Rx.combineLatest2(streamA, streamB, (a, b) => [a, b]);


   return Scaffold(
    appBar: MyAppBar(),
    body:CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: Container(
            height: 10.0,
          ),
        ),
       StreamBulder(
       stream: combineStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: Center(
                    child: circularProgressBar(),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
              List<QuerySnapshot> _list = [];
                _list.addAll(getList(snapshot.data[0]));
                _list.addAll(getList(snapshot.data[1]));
                if (_list.length == 0) {
                } else {
                  return SliverList(
                    delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                      (context, index) {
                        ProductModel model = ProductModel.fromJson(
                           _list[index].docs[index].data());

                        return cartSourceInfo(model, context,
                            removeCartFunction: () =>
                                removeItemFromUserCart(model.shortInfo));
                      },
                      childCount: childCount: snapshot.hasData ? _list.length : 0,
                    ),
                  );
                }
              }
            }    
       )
    );
 }
}
```

Majority of the answers here are using Observable library which is deplecated in rxdart, and when am trying to use the same syntax to solve using Rx.latestCombine2 there is no data streamed. and when I try to pass a querySnapshot of type list to a stream Stream<List> I am getting a batch of errors:

Class 'List' has no instance getter 'docs'.
Receiver: Instance(length:2) of '_GrowableList'
Tried calling: docs

Please show me how I can either nest these two firebase stream into ome or how I can use Rx.combineLatest2 method to solve this problem.

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to combine multiple stream into one stream. I think I am missing something out.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax looks correct but when trying to access data of each stream you have to access it by index since the snapshot is basically a list

so to access snapshot of stream1 and stream2 it should be accesssed like this

`snapshot.data[0].docs`  and  `snapshot.data[1].docs`  respectively.

You can combine both the streams and show the list in the Ui, And make sure to assign a appropriate type `T` based on the type of `snapshot.data[index].docs`

```
 List<QuerySnapshot> combineLists(
      List<QuerySnapshot> list1, List<QuerySnapshot> list2) {
    List<QuerySnapshot> result = [];
    list1.forEach((element) {
      result.add(element);
    });
    list2.forEach((element) {
      result.add(element);
    });
    return result;
  }

StreamBulder(
 ​stream: combineStream,
 ​builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<QuerySnapshot>> snapshot) {
   ​if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      ​return SliverToBoxAdapter(
        ​child: Center(
          ​child: circularProgressBar(),
          ​),
        ​);
      ​} else {​
         final List<QuerySnapshot> _list=[];
         final List<QuerySnapshot> combineSnapshot =
                    combineLists(snapshot.data[0], snapshot.data[1]);
         ​if (_list.length == 0) {
            ​return addItems();
         ​} else {
             return SliverList(
                ​delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (context, index) {
                     ProductModel model = ProductModel.fromJson(
                     _list[index].data());
                 return cartSourceInfo(model, context, removeCartFunction: 
                    () => removeItemFromUserCart(model.shortInfo));
                 ​},
                 childCount:_list.length,
                 ),
               );
           ​}
        }
   }
```

Comment: So far so good I have managed to access the snapshot of the two stream. Thank you very much. But now how can I update my childCount to count the length of both streams. I have tried  (snapshot.data[0].docs.length + snapshot.data[1].docs.length)  but am getting - RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

Comment: cna you add some more detail to your question what data are you trying to show in the Ui and from which collection and what is the structure of the collection?

Comment: do you want to show both streams data in a list?

Comment: According to your Answer above, Inside SliverchildBuilderDelegate, I have created two object 

`ProductModel model = ProductModel.fromJson(snapshot.data[0].docs[index].data());`

`ProductModel flashSalemodel = ProductModel.fromJson(snapshot.data[1].docs[index].data());`

When I use one object it is working well, But when I use both object I am getting 
`RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1`

Comment: I have updated the answer check just assign a proprt type T

Comment: Thanks alot, I think this is the last problem I have, I have tried using `QuerySnapshot` and `DocumentSnapshot` as a return type `T` though am getting 'type QuerySnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast` and 'type DocumentSnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'QuerySnapshot' in type cast' respectively. Otherwise your logic is making sense 100%

Comment: can you tell me what is the type of snapshot?

Comment: It is a list of documents, so the type is QuerySnapshot

Comment: We have changed our snapshot to a `AsyncSnapshot` `List<QuerySnapshot>` so I am getting this error The argument type 'QuerySnapshot' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<QuerySnapshot>'. and How do we add docs to the empty `_list` we created.

Comment: check the line no where exactly you are getting the error and then we can change the type accordingly

Comment: final List<QuerySnapshot> combineSnapshot =
                    combineLists(snapshot.data[0], snapshot.data[1]);
Both  parameters we passing to combineLists.